# google maps - remove marker icon dynamically from javascript

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-markers

i have a web page in which whenever user visit that page he can see his last location. there is a button also on the top of the page called "getCurrentlocation". when user clicks on this button the map refreshes and shows him the current location. the problem is when map refreshes  it displays two marker icons on the map. one is the first when he visits the page and second when he pressed the button. this is because i have coded two maps on my php page. so according to my condition i don't want to change it to only one code for map. so i want to do something like when user clicks the button and the location is successfully fetched i want to remove the old marker icon. is there any id of that old marker icon so i can remove it.hope you understand my question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [Google Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) to support JavaScript in Google Maps on your site.
[Here you have information](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove), how to remove marker by it.